# Not able to get callback on exception after Control.Invoke()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

I have 2 threads. Thread-1, that has a UserControl and Thread-2 that has a delegate method. In Thread 2,

i) I need to invoke the delegate on Thread-1.

ii) Depending on if any exception happened or not, execute some additional logic

This is what I am doing. In Thread-1, before control creation, I have registered a callback

```
Application.ThreadException += MyUIExceptionHandler(); 
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

**Question-1:**
Now, In Thread-2, when I call  `thread1Control.BeginInvoke(myDelegateMethod, args)` I do get the callback to `MyUIExceptionHandler()` on the occurence of an exception but since `Control.BeginInvoke` is asynchronous I do not know how much time to wait before I execute step ii) mentioned above. A simple `Thread.Sleep(5000)` after the call to `BeginInvoke()` does the job for me and it should be done in that way I know. But what is my other alternative for achieving this?
*PS:I cannot do any notify stuff from the UserControl side as I do not have control over that code!*

**Question-2:**
And if I use `thread1Control.Invoke(myDelegateMethod, args)` which is a synchronous call seems to fit the bill perfectly but when there is an exception I do not get callback to `MyUIExceptionHandler()`. Why do I NOT get a callback ih this case?

Answer (score 1):

Control.BeginInvoke() is a fire-and-forget method.  Since your thread has moved on elsewhere, might not even be running anymore, any exception raised by the target is raised on the UI thread.

Control.Invoke() is a fire-and-wait-until-done method.  Your worker thread is blocked until the target finished executing.  Since you use that method only when you are interested in the outcome, any exception raised by the target is re-raised on your worker thread.  You'll have to catch it if you want to keep the program running.

Comment: Invoke() does not give me callback on exception. BeginIvoke() does. For now, I am using BeginInvoke() and using thread synchronization. So, that solves my problem and also answers question-1 but question-2 remains unanswered.

Comment: It should be clear from the answer why this is so.  The exception is re-raised on the thread.  You'll need to wrap your Invoke() call with try/catch.